# Braintree iOS Integration

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, payment-gateway, braintree

I am trying to implement payment in iOS. I tried your sandbox testing with help of https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4

After adding card number "4111111111111111" , I am completely blind what's do next?
Rightnow, I don't have any server.

Questions:

1)What is Expiry date of card "4111111111111111"?

2) After Adding card tap, what should be next step to complete transaction?

3) Is own server required for successful transaction?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I tried in Swift it's working fine for me. I attached the code below check and let me know:

```
    var braintree: Braintree?
     braintree = Braintree(clientToken: "")



    func userDidCancelPayment() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func drop(_ viewController: BTDropInViewController!, didSucceedWith paymentMethod: BTPaymentMethod!) {

        print(paymentMethod.nonce)

        // Send payment method nonce to your server

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Send payment method nonce to your server Sucessfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

 func tappedMyPayButton() 
{
 let dropInViewController = braintree!.dropInViewController(with: self)
        dropInViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel, target: self, action: #selector(PaymentVController.userDidCancelPayment))

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dropInViewController)
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    func drop(inViewControllerDidCancel viewController: BTDropInViewController!) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Visa: 4242 4242 4242 4242
Mastercard: 5555 5555 5555 4444
American Express: 3782 822463 10005
Important note: Use any future Expiration Date, Name on card, CVC, and Billing Zip in test mode.